# An English equivalent of the Japanese idiom "to view (someone) through colored glasses", meaning they are viewed with bias/prejudice

Tags: translation, idiom-request

The Japanese idiom "to view (someone) through colored glasses" means "to view (someone) with bias/prejudice."

Is there an English equivalent of this Japanese idiom?

[Note] The Japanese idiom almost always has a negative implication, as illustrated in the following dialog.

> Yuki: Kenichi said I wouldn't be able to solve this math problem.
>
> Reiko: Really?
>
> Yuki: Yup. He seems to have a bias that women are not suited for mathematics.
>
> Reiko: He should stop viewing women through colored glasses!

Comment: In English, *rose-colored glasses* means all pink and pretty, but unrealistically.

Comment: No one's mentioned "jade-colored glasses" yet?

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's not entirely true; not pretty and pink, but optimistically, positive - see [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rose-colored-glasses) definition "a happy or positive attitude that fails to notice negative things, leading to a view of life that is not realistic" MW & Collins have similar definitions and it even has its own Wikipedia page. The OP states that they are looking for a negative version, so cannot use as an answer

Comment: For what it’s worth, I think a direct translation as used in this answer is perfectly understandable to a native English speaker, it just lacks the inherent negative connotation of the original. In the right context though, like in the example in this question though, that shouldn’t matter much. A native idiom is obviously preferred, but in a pinch this works just fine in my opinion.

Comment: The technical term is *cognitive bias*; https://happiful.com/what-is-cognitive-bias-the-halo-effect-and-horn-effect

Comment: The phrase "jade colored glasses" is unknown in English.  You may be thinking of "jaded view".

Comment: @Fattie It seems like some folks understand it as a play on "rose colored glasses" + "jaded" from some of the comments on the EL&U question  [Pessimism idiom - opposite of rose-tinted glasses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/174738/80039)

Comment: @ColleenV That phrase isn't super responsive to the question though--the wordplay is pretty likely to be understood, but it reads as novel rather than idiomatic.

Comment: @Tiercelet Sure, I’m not arguing for it as an answer. I just objected to the “unknown in English” because it jumped to mind for quite a few native English speakers.

Comment: Note also the English phrase "to see through a glass darkly" from 1 Cor 13, which does NOT mean "to see in a negative light" but rather "to see without great clarity".

Comment: In all this discussion regarding "rose colored glasses", "dim light", or "jaundiced view" and whether or not these are regularly used or understood in modern English vernacular, it's probably worth noting that the most common and culturally understood modern idiom of this type is "beer goggles". Like rose colored glasses make you see someone as more virtuous than they really are, beer goggles make someone more attractive than they really are.

Answer (score 19):

The expression "(have a) jaundiced view" of something, or "(look on something with a) jaundiced eye" means to have a negative bias against something - to only see its bad points.

> He should have a less jaundiced view of women.

> Hamlet's jaundiced view of women is expressed viciously to Ophelia and stems from what he feels as his betrayal by her and his mother,  Gertrude

In contrast to look at something through "rose-tinted glasses"  has the opposite sense, to only look at the positive aspects of something, and so be biased in its favour.

Comment: Thank you, James. I've edited the OP. The Japanese idiom is used when describing people, not things.

Comment: It could be used of people too, though I'm not sure how "natural" this sounds. In the "mathematics" example

Comment: The difference seems to be that Hamlet's jaundiced view means that he sees only the faults in Ophelia and his Mother and applies these to all women.  They both have faults. Hamlet's error is "faulty generalisation" and is about the morals of women.  But the OP's example isn't generalising and it isn't about the morals, but about the abilities of women.  It would probably be better not to use a figure of speech and just say that "He is biased"

Comment: You have a typo (too small for me to edit) in your first paragraph: "express" instead of "expression". I usually hear "rose-coloured spectacles", by the way. Do you know which is more common?

Comment: rose-titnted or rose-coloured are both fine,  Glasses or spectacles, also both are fine.

Comment: Whilst I always love JamesK answers, I think it's worth noting "jaundiced view" is not something you'd say in casual conversation here in the 2000s. It's more of a phrase that would be used in an article or essay, I'd say.

Comment: @Fattie Totally agree. I'd also like to add that I'm a native speaker and I've never seen it before and I'd have to look it up if I saw it. I'd get that it's negative, but not the specifics.

Comment: I agree with Fattie and wjandrea . This is not a common saying and it might not be easily understood without looking it up.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the "jaundiced view" offered by another, you can say someone has a jaded view, a bitter view, a negative view, a prejudice against, warped perspective.

If you want to go more extreme you can use words involving poison, venom, toxic.

> He has a bitter view of women owing to...
>
> Bob's a great guy, but he needs to stop having such a poisoned view of women.
>
> Sally needs to stop looking at men through her warped perspective.

Comment: Of these I think "having a warped perspective (of someone or something) best fits the OP's "looking through colored glasses" meaning of "bias or predjudice". It definitely has negative connotations.

Comment: "jaded view" has a totally different unrelated meaning. See dictionary

Comment: @Fattie Yeah, totally different connotation. [Webster says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded): "made dull, apathetic, or cynical by experience or by having or seeing too much of something". Here, "cynical" applies, but "by experience or by ... seeing too much of something" doesn't. (Or it could, hypothetically, but it'd imply a *lot* about the speaker.)

Answer (score 3):

I like the answers you've already received of "jaundiced view" or "bad light." I think you might also see "X takes a dim view of ___" though that indicates skepticism or cynicism more than personal bias--if I heard that sentence, I would think that X might be a little overly judgmental or prickly, but I wouldn't think of X as being prejudiced, specifically.

However, if the expression you're using is about bias specifically, I think nowadays people would be less likely to use any general-purpose idiom in this context. Instead, I would expect most speakers--especially younger people and those who are more aware of different kinds of social biases--to name the specific kind of bias. So in your example, I would expect something like:

> Yuki: Kenichi said I wouldn't be able to solve this math problem.
>
> Reiko: Really?
>
> Yuki: Yup. He seems to have a bias that women are not suited for mathematics.
>
> Reiko: <strike>He should stop viewing women through colored glasses!</strike> He shouldn't be so misogynistic! [or: What a misogynist!]

Now, depending on context, that might be seen as a little harsh--and it may have political overtones, since it identifies the speaker as someone who believes in gender equality and has vocabulary around that issue.

If we're looking for something less formal, I could imagine:

> Reiko: He shouldn't look down on women like that!

or maybe even:

> Reiko: Why's he hatin' on women like that?

with that one being considerably more casual.

I'll also point out that Kenichi would probably be offended by any of these if he heard them. (I'm not sure if he would be offended or embarrassed if he'd heard the original Japanese phrase.)

Comment: I agree. Reiko could also have replied: "Whatever, forget that sexist asshole!" Note that Kenichi would certainly be offended if he heard this.

Answer (score 2):

English has a very similar idiom for an *optimistic* bias, “to view (someone) through [**rose**-colored glasses”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rose-colored%20glasses).

A possible negative counterpart is [jade-colored glasses](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JadeColoredGlasses), which is wordplay on being [jaded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded) (or perhaps [green with envy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/green%20with%20envy)), as well as being a contrasting color.  However, this is a fairly recent coinage, and not as popular as the “rose” version.

Better-known idioms based on the idea of *looking* at a person with a negative perspective are to see them through a **dark lens** or a **[jaundiced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaundiced) eye**.

If you're a big fan of alliteration, you might look at the person through a “pessimistic prism” or “skeptical spectacles”.  (These aren't established phrases, just suggestions.)

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing, which is commonplace and current, is just

#### .. "in a bad light".

> <strike>Yuki</strike> Jenny: Kenichi said I wouldn't be able to solve this math problem.
>
> <strike>Reiko</strike> Sandy: Really?
>
> <strike>Yuki</strike> Jenny: Yup. He seems to have a bias that women are not suited for
> mathematics.
>
> <strike>Reiko</strike> Sandy: He always sees women in a bad light.

Even that expression is a little archaic, somewhat formal. It's unlikely a young person would use the expression.

I can't think of a current expression commonly used in speech, for the sense in question.

Comment: I'm surprised you think this is archaic/formal--I mean, sure it's not gen-z slang, but it's not exactly Chaucer either. But I think you're right in the sense that I'd not expect an idiom here at all, but just some specific concrete language.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "bad light" for a *perception*, only for a *depiction*, like say, "The way you told that story put me in a bad light."